# Elasticsearch: "One index with many shards" vs. "Many indices with one shard per index"

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, elastic-stack, elk

My Elasticsearch hardware config has 3 nodes:

- 2 x data, master, ingest node with 64GB RAM (30GB of that go to JVM), 3TB HDD, 8 Cores each;
- 1 x master + coordinating node with 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD, 2 Cores.

---

My data is:

- ≈ 5 billions of documents, that take ≈ 1.5-2TB of disk space currently (will grow up to 10TB in a year);
- complex structure, with a lot of nested documents (that are included in parents), also fields in docs are not standartized at all (and can't be), so index mappings are huge;
- data is not over-time (like logs);

---

I need to be able to search on any field in these docs, the **search is performed only on all the documents via String Query API**. Also during search I use *sort*, *highlighting*, *total_hits_count* and *terms aggregation*.

Personally, I've tried two attempts to store pr:

- **1 index with 16 shards** - that leads to long index times, but fast search speed. Also nodes crashed on a regular bases, cause (I think) mappings were too big and I always had around 95-99 RAM usage on nodes.
- **16 indexes with 1 shard each**, with assigned alias - indexing stage is performed faster, however search became a lot slower. *This is current version.*

I don't get why search on 1x16 is a lot faster, than 16x1...

---

So finally what is the best approach to store this data in ES, based on provided info?

Also each shard currently weighs 75-128GB, when it's recommended to keep shard size 20-50GB, but I saw opinion and recommendation to keep 1 shard per core. So opinions on that configuration are welcomed as well.

Comment: How many replicas are you using? Since you have only two data nodes, you need at least one replica, so in case that one of your nodes failing, you will not lose access to your data. The basica shards recommendations are to keep it below 50 GB and to have less then 20 shards for each GB in the heap per node. Did you head this [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) from elastic?

Comment: Yes, I've read that post. Currently I have 1 primary and 1 replica for each of 16 indexes.